# Shell Program if statements aren't working

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement, unix

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Wishing according to Time of the PC"
h=$(date  '+%H')  #This line works, I've Checked.
if test $h -gt 6 -a $h -lt 12
then
    echo "Good Morning"
elif test $h -gt 12 -a $h -lt 16
then
    echo "Good Afternoon"
elif test $h -gt 16 -a $h -lt 20
then
    echo "Good Evening"
else
    echo "Good Night"
fi
```

Output should be coming according to My PC's time which is 4:00 PM  but the above code isn't executing that `if` and `elif` conditions (I mean, if and elif are always returning false) and is directly jumping to `else` part. I am using Linux 7.9. I tried using nested if as well but it returns false always as well.

Comment: Works for me...  (Mac, sh, bash and zsh)

Comment: Yes, It works on some devices. I asked my friends to try this code and it worked on some pcs and didn't on some. I don't know what's the Problem is.

Comment: Very strange. Not all linuxes and shells are simar but this seems to be pretty basic.

Comment: I would try debugging with printouts (echo) one condition at a time. Without -a, just -gt/-lt

Comment: @YaroslavFyodorov I've tried that. If there is a single if condition, it works and when I give multiple if condition by using '-a' then that returns false for some reason. The thing is that, I tried this in my college and it worked fine. I copied the code and sent myself and when I tried it on my pc, it didn't work.

Comment: Actually, I've never seen -a before, I am used to [ $a -gt 2 ] && [ $a -lt 5 ]; or similar. Try this perhaps. It still doesn't explain what's the matter with -a though

Comment: It looks like you are using some non-standard shell.

Comment: @YaroslavFyodorov, `-a` and `-o` used to be very common to combine multiple tests into one invocation (from when `test` was an external executable and slow to invoke), though it's marked obsolescent now

Comment: @Dilip, btw, "Linux 7.9" doesn't exist. Linux itself, as of this writing, is up to version 6.0-rc4; see https://kernel.org/. (I assume you're talking about something like "Red Hat Linux 7.9", but in that case 7.9 is the version of Red Hat Linux, not the version of Linux itself that Red Hat is packaging -- that's an important distinction because it's your distributor, like Red Hat or Ubuntu, that decides what version of bash and other tools they're going to include in each of their releases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you're not capturing when $h *is* 16
- only when it's *less* or *more*
- see `-ge` (greater than *or equal to*) in the below

allow me to make this more idiomatic (use of `test` is not current practice, use `[[ ... ]]`):

```bash
h=$(date '+%H')
h=${h#0}        # remove leading zero
if   [[ $h -gt 6  && $h -lt 12 ]]
then
    echo "Good Morning"
elif [[ $h -ge 12 && $h -lt 16 ]]
then
    echo "Good Afternoon"
elif [[ $h -ge 16 && $h -lt 20 ]]
then
    echo "Good Evening"
else
    echo "Good Night"
fi
```

note that I remove any leading zero,
this is because a leading zero can make a number (e.g. `09`)
interpreted as an octal, which is not what you want!

Comment: `-a` is a POSIX-ism; in `[[`, use `&&` instead.

Comment: Also, if you're going to use bash-only syntax like `[[`, think about `(( h > 6 )) && (( h < 12 ))`; more natural to use math syntax than test's `-gt` and `-lt`.

Comment: (to be clear, `test` _is_ current practice for people writing code for POSIX sh; `[[` is a ksh/bash/zsh extension, but its presence is not guaranteed by the standard -- what _is_ outdated when writing code for POSIX is the use of `-a`, which is marked obsolescent; one should use `test "$h" -gt 6 && test "$h" -lt 12` to avoid ambiguity when writing POSIXy code)

Comment: all fair comments, @CharlesDuffy but when it's tagged `linux` and has `#!/bin/bash` I assume the person isn't looking for a POSIX answer

Comment: Right now, though, this code is wrong as given and needs an [edit]. Try running `[[ foo -a bar ]]`; on bash 5.1, I get `bash: conditional binary operator expected`
`bash: syntax error near '-a'`. Replacing `-a` with `&&` when using `[[` is not optional.

Comment: Ha, you are right, it's specifically 4pm that falls through to "good night".